# calling functions using "->"

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm currently learning about virtual functions, and in this particular lesson it creates an array of object pointers `firstArray[5]`, and calls functions from these objects. Until now, whenever I wanted to call a function `func()` from an object `foo`, I would write `foo.func()`. Now that I'm using virtual functions and this array, the book has switched to this method: `firstArray[0]->func()`. The book doesn't do a great job at justifying this switch, could someone please explain? I see that when I try to use `firstArray[0].func()`, I get this....

`error: request for member 'func' in 'firstArray[0]', which is of non-class type 'sampleClass*'`.

Is it simply because I'm trying to call a function from a pointer, not an actual object? I've been learning C++ for several months now, and for whatever reason pointers still trip me up sometimes. Any clarification would help.

EDIT:

I think the part that got me mixed up is this: I can create a pointer to a base object class with `base *ptr;`. Then, I can set that pointer by creating a new object from a derived class by saying `ptr = new derived;`. This is where I get confused. If I were to create an `int* ptr;`, and I wanted it to point to a integer I create, I couldn't say `ptr = int j`. If `ptr` is really just an address, why do these two examples work differently? I guess I don't understand the "new" mechanic very well either.

Comment: You are right. It is because you are calling a function from a pointer. Using 'foo->func()' is short for '(*foo).func()'

Comment: Is it an array of pointers? You must use either (*var).func() or var->func() to call functions on pointer variables. Maybe you should read the chapter about pointers again, or if you didn't yet, do it now. : )

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have no idea why pointers in particular get me caught up, I really haven't struggled with any of the other chapters. knowing that 'foo->func()' is short for '(*foo).func()' makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't have anything to do with virtual functions. If you have a pointer you need operator-> to deference and access the object it's pointing to....

You could still use the operator. (dot) to access the members/functions if you dereference first:

```
(*foo).func()
```

A pointer to an object just holds the address where the object is held in memory.
So if you have a variable which is a pointer to some type, it actually holds a number.

If you want to use the object, you need to call the object it is pointing to, which is as I said by using either operator* or operator. (dot).

Comment: I realize now it doesn't have anything to do with virtual functions, which is why I was so confused when this was the first time the book had called a function that way after 11 or so chapters. I assumed they were related but clearly they are not. Much appreciated.